# Image sliding in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image slider widget in my application. I am using jquery cycle for that.. I have a drop down menu where I can change the effects of the slider. But I need to insert this image slider in more than one place in a single page. And for the drop down menu I have used id.. so when I insert the image in more than one page in a single page the effect would be same for all (as I hve used the id).. So I wanted to give a class name for drop down menu.. In that case how would i assign the effects value in jquery.. Please find the code below.. Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.?/ (I am just learning jquery and JS).
Jquery code:

```
var effects_id = document.getElementById('slideshow_effects').value;
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js'/></script><script type='text/javascript' src='/javascripts/jquery.cycle.all.min.js'/></script>

<script type='text/javascript'> 
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.editor_slideshow').cycle({
            fx: '"+effects_id+"',
            speed: 1000,
            timeout: 2000
        });});
</script>
```

Drop down menu:

```
<select id="slideshow_effects">
<option value="fade">Fade</option>
<option value="fadeZoom">FadeZoom</option>
<option value="cover">Cover</option>
<option value="toss">Toss</option>
<option value="blindY">BlindY</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It would be better if I could get the value of effects through javascript rather than using jquery to get it... To assign the value I can use jquery code...

Answer (score 0):

In these cases I would the following structure:

```
<div class='slider'>
    <select class='drop' >...</select>
    <div class='slideshow'></div>
</div>
```

now in js:

```
$(".slider").each(slider_init);

function slider_init(index, el)
{
    var drop = $(el).find(".drop");
    var slideshow = $(el).find(".slideshow");

    // now initialize slider here for drop and slideshow
    slideshow.cycle({
        fx: drop.val(),
        speed: 1000,
        timeout: 2000
    });});
}
```

actually this way you initialize each occurrence of your slider individually and for each initialization the code finds the relevant select element.

This way no matter how many "sliders" you have on page, each will work individually

Comment: how do I do this using javascript.. If i provide the id for each options then how can i get the value of that particular options id??

Comment: so wot does the el and index would contain initially.. i see that it is used as var drop = $(el).find(".drop");
and variable index is not used anywhere... I am confused.. :) I am just started to learn jquery:)

Comment: Is there a way to do it using pure JS

Comment: just saw an issue in my code (copy/paste u know) editor_slideshow is named slider in my code. (the element in which u load the slidershow). this is much more readable than pure JS. just read the core carefully and u will see what's going on :)